# View operation in salesforce using apex and visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Below are the code of my VF and controller class 
The save and cancel method works fine but my search method is not working correctly. After saving the objects when i click the view button it says to enter the field name instead of showing the list of objects.
VF code

```
<apex:page controller="c5">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.First_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Contact_Number__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="view" action="{!search}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller class

```
public class c5
{

    public PageReference cancel() 
    {
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Reg');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;

    }

    List<Register__c> b = new List<Register__c>();
    Register__c a = new Register__c();

    public Register__c geta(){
    return a;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
    insert a;
    return null;
    }

    public List<Register__c> getb(){
    return b;
    }
    public PageReference search(){
    b = (List<Register__c>)[select Name, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Email__c, Contact_Number__c  from Register__c];
    return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the result of your search to the property `b` but you don't display / use this property in the VisualForce page.

Try something like this:

```
<apex:page controller="c5">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.First_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Contact_Number__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="view" action="{!search}" rerender="bData"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="bData">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!b}" var="theSObject" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(b))}">
                <apex:column value="{!theSobject.Name}"/>
            </apex:dataTable
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```